# How to evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{A+B\cos\theta}$?

Tags: calculus

I'm having a trouble with this integral expression:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{A+B \cos\theta}$$

I've done this substitution: $t= \tan(\theta/2)$

and get: $\displaystyle \cos\theta= \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $\displaystyle d\theta=\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$ where $\displaystyle \cos^2\theta/2=\frac{1}{1+t^2}$

then the integral becomes:

$$\int\frac{2 \, dt}{(A-B)t^2+(A+B)}= \sqrt\frac{A+B}{A-B} \arctan \left(\left(\sqrt\frac{A+B}{A-B} \right) t\right)$$

However, I'm not sure about the new limits since $\tan$ has period $\pi$ so what I have to do at this point to decide the new limits? And of course if you find some mistake in what I've done before, please let me know!

Comment: Hint: $ \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{A+B\cos\theta} = 2 \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} \frac{d\theta}{A+B\cos\theta}.$

Comment: Are you dealing with explicit $A$ and $B$? Sometimes the integral will not even converge.

Comment: By the way, you don't have to use Weierstrass substitution that explicitly since we can write: $$ \begin{aligned}I & = \frac{1}{a+b\cos{x}}\\& =\frac{1}{a\left(\sin^2 \frac{1}{2}x+\cos^2\frac{1}{2}x\right)+b\left(\cos^2 {\frac{1}{2}x}-\sin^2\frac{1}{2}x\right)} \\& =\frac{1}{(a-b)\sin^2\frac{1}{2}x+(a+b)\cos^2\frac{1}{2}x} \\& =\frac{\sec^2{\frac{1}{2}x}}{(a+b)+(a-b)\tan^2\frac{1}{2}x}. \end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 12):

To avoid confusion with limits, note that
$$\int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{dx}{a+b \cos(x)} = \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \dfrac{dx}{a+b \cos(x)}$$
Hence, we have
$$I = \int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{dx}{a+b \cos(x)} = 2\int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{dx}{a+b \cos(x)}$$
Now use your substitution $t = \tan(x/2)$ and note that $t$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$ as $x$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$.

**EDIT**

An easier way if you are familiar with a little bit of complex analysis is as follows.

Let $z = e^{ix}$. Then we have that $dz = iz dx$. Hence,
\begin{align}
I & = \int_0^{2 \pi} \dfrac{dx}{a+b \cos(x)} = \oint_{\vert z \vert = 1} \dfrac{dz}{iz \left( a + \dfrac{b}2 \left(z+ \dfrac1z \right)\right)}\\
& = \dfrac1i \oint_{\vert z \vert = 1} \dfrac{dz}{az + \dfrac{b}2 \left(z^2+1 \right)} = \dfrac2{ib} \oint_{\vert z \vert = 1}\dfrac{dz}{z^2 + \dfrac{2a}b z + 1}\\
& = \dfrac2{ib} \oint_{\vert z \vert = 1} \dfrac{dz}{\left(z + \dfrac{a}b \right)^2 + 1 - \dfrac{a^2}{b^2}} = \dfrac2{ib} \oint_{\vert z \vert = 1} \dfrac{dz}{\left(z + r + \sqrt{r^2-1} \right)\left(z + r - \sqrt{r^2-1} \right)}
\end{align}
where $r = \dfrac{a}b \in \mathbb{R}$.

First note that if $\vert r \vert \leq 1$, then $\left \vert r \pm \sqrt{r^2-1} \right \vert = 1$. Hence, the integral doesn't exist.

If $r > 1$, then $ \left \vert r + \sqrt{r^2 - 1} \right \vert > 1$ and $\left \vert r - \sqrt{r^2-1} \right \vert < 1$. Hence, by [Cauchy integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), we have that
$$I = \dfrac{2}{ib} 2 \pi i \dfrac1{2 \sqrt{r^2-1}} = \dfrac{2 \pi \, \text{sign}(a)}{\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}$$

If $r < -1$, then $\left \vert r - \sqrt{r^2 - 1} \right \vert > 1$ and $\left \vert r + \sqrt{r^2-1} \right \vert < 1$. Hence, by [Cauchy integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), we have that
$$I = \dfrac{2}{ib} 2 \pi i \dfrac{-1}{2 \sqrt{r^2-1}} = \dfrac{2 \pi \, \text{sign}(a)}{\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}$$
Hence, to summarize,
$$I = \begin{cases} \dfrac{2 \pi \, \text{sign}(a)}{\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}} & \text{if } \vert a \vert > \vert b\\ \text{Does not exists} & \text{if } \vert a \vert \leq \vert b\end{cases}$$

Comment: But you'd better have $|a| > |b|$ to avoid zeros of the denominator.

Comment: how did you go from the $z$ and $a,b$ to the $z$ and the $r$ denoninator?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you want to do your substitution on a domain where it is defined, continuous, and invertible.

That's not quite true here, as [this plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%20t/2%20for%20t%20from%200%20to%202%20pi) shows.

But we can carefully break the domain up into parts where the substitution behaves nicely, sort of, by splitting $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi]$ into two regions $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ and $\theta \in [\pi, 2 \pi]$. Note that we really should break the integral up into two integrals, one over each domain.

Over $\theta \in [0,\pi]$, $t$ varies from $0$ to $+\infty$; so the substitution is problematic! However, you can still set up the *improper* integral, and take care to show that it converges to the right thing.

You can treat $\theta \in [\pi, 2\pi]$ similarly.

Of course, once you've set that up, it's clear you can put the integrals back together, since $\int_0^{+\infty} f + \int_{-\infty}^0 f = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f$. You could have observed this by changing the original limits of integration from $[0, 2\pi]$ to $[-\pi, \pi]$ because the integrand was periodic.

P.S. there's one extra problem with your integral: the integrand diverges at the $\theta$ where $A + B \cos \theta = 0$. Such solutions exist if $|A| \leq |B|$. So you have to handle the improperness of that as well. (notice that your solution method for the transformed integral assumes this, and possibly more)

Answer (score 0):

By periodicity and parity of $\cos$
$$
\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{d\theta}{A+B\cos\theta}=\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} \dfrac{d\theta}{A+B\cos\theta}=2\int\limits_0^{\pi} \dfrac{d\theta}{A+B\cos\theta}
$$

Answer (score 0):

As $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, $\theta/2$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$, so $\tan(\theta/2)$ goes from $0$ up to $+\infty$ and then from $-\infty$ up to $0$.  Add the two together and you get $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty$.